# Creating Scoped Job Requests For Quickbooks Web Connector QBWC?

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbwc

I'm developing a web application that communicates with many different Web Connectors, sometimes simultaneously.

The problem I'm running into is that I have a single, global job queue on the server that all Web Connectors are polling from.

Is there any way to create an XML job request that *specifies* which Web Connector should run a particular job? I'm wondering if the OwnerID tag could be used to match a job to a specific local .qwc configuration? Or possibly FileID? Beyond these two variables, I can't imagine I have any additional control over influencing the Web Connector to make a decision to run a specific job or not.

I'm trying to avoid having each individual Web Connector run every single job on the queue, whether it was intended for them or not.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The Web Connector itself doesn't have any logic like this - it's up to your SOAP server implementation to only feed the correct requests to the Web Connector.

This is what the username parameter in the .QWC files/Web Connector is for.

If you have a single username, everything gets sent to just a single Web Connector.

If you have multiple usernames, then you specify which username to queue up each request under, and only the Web Connector with the .QWC file with that username in will run the corresponding items that were queued up for that username.

When you create your .QWC files, use the corresponding usernames in the .QWC files.